# lucene BooleanQuery equals/in

Tags: java, lucene

I am searching in lucene with a "equals" operator implemented like:

```
return new TermQuery(new Term(getName(), getValue()));
```

for a vale like: customerID:YADA-UT-08ec5de9-8813-4361-be88-55695ddfaa00

This is working.

BUT, if i use an "in" operator implemented with a BooleanQuery like;

```
final BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
for (final String aValue : value) {
    booleanQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term(getName(), aValue)), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
}
```

it will not find any customer with YADA-UT-08ec5de9-8813-4361-be88-55695ddfaa00

After a lot of tests i am assuming that the length of 'YADA-UT-08ec5de9-8813-4361-be88-55695ddfaa00' or dashes can be the problem. (i use token to keep it in db) when using with BooleanQuery.

Any clue ?

EDIT: What is strange is that:
- this is working with "in" (Boolean query): 25c20c21-bd88-4a6d-aa02-209b5fb6fb11
- this is not working with it:               YADA-UT-08ec5de9-8813-4361-be88-55695ddfaa00

Solution Found: the lucene words were indexed as lower case :)

Comment: Try calling `toString()` on the `Query` objects, this gives you a textual representation of what will be executed, and can be very useful for debugging

Comment: Generally you should use the same analyzer when indexing and parsing query string. Lowercasing filter is a part of StandardAnalyzer.

Comment: fyi - if you find a solution, its best to post it as the answer to your own question :-)

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it, on a daily basis I see this question I click to answer it only to realize it has been already solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange solution for me but...that's it:)

> the lucene words were indexed as lower
>   case :)